# Concatenate with non-variable stuff in perl

Tags: perl, concatenation

I need to concate `map` result with a string.

```
perl -le 'print (map { (q(a)..q(z))[rand(26)] } 1..3) . "123"'
```

Expected 3 random symbols and `123`. But there is no `123` just 3 random symbols.
In general, I need to add a variable there.

Answer (score 3):

With warnings:

```
print (...) interpreted as function at -e line 1.
Useless use of concatenation (.) or string in void context at -e line 1.
```

This is because your code is of the following form:

```
print(...) . "123"
```

Solutions:

```
perl -le'print( map( { (q(a)..q(z))[rand(26)] } 1..3 ) . "123" )'   # Fully parenthesized
perl -le'print map( { (q(a)..q(z))[rand(26)] } 1..3 ) . "123"'      # Opt parens dropped
perl -le'print( ( map { (q(a)..q(z))[rand(26)] } 1..3 ) . "123" )'
perl -le'print +( map { (q(a)..q(z))[rand(26)] } 1..3 ) . "123"'    # "Disambiguated"
```

Except those aren't right either. While they fix the problem you asked about, they reveal a second problem. They invariably print `3123` because `map` in scalar context returns the number of scalars it would otherwise return in list context.

Solutions:

```
perl -le'print( map( { (q(a)..q(z))[rand(26)] } 1..3 ), "123" )'         # . => ,
perl -le'print map( { (q(a)..q(z))[rand(26)] } 1..3 ), "123"'            # . => ,
perl -le'print( ( map { (q(a)..q(z))[rand(26)] } 1..3 ), "123" )'        # . => ,
perl -le'print +( map { (q(a)..q(z))[rand(26)] } 1..3 ), "123"'          # . => ,
perl -le'print join "", ( map { (q(a)..q(z))[rand(26)] } 1..3 ), "123"'  # join
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of interesting things going on here. First let's ask Perl to help up track down any problems by turning on warnings.

```
$ perl -Mwarnings -le 'print (map { (q(a)..q(z))[rand(26)] } 1..3) . "123"'
print (...) interpreted as function at -e line 1.
Useless use of concatenation (.) or string in void context at -e line 1.
lfy
```

Two warnings there. Let's look at both of them.

> print (...) interpreted as function

If the first non-whitespace character following `print` (or any other list operator) is a opening parenthesis, then Perl assumes that you want to call `print` as a function and it will look for the balancing closing parenthesis to end the list of arguments to `print`.

> Useless use of concatenation (.) or string in void context

Because the `print` call is assumed to end with the closing parenthesis, the `. "123"` isn't doing anything useful. And is therefore ignored.

The standard way to tell Perl that an opening parenthesis isn't marking a function call is to use a `+`.

```
$ perl -Mwarnings -le 'print +(map { (q(a)..q(z))[rand(26)] } 1..3) . "123"'
3123
```

Well, we lost the warnings. But we got '3' where we were hoping to see three symbols. What we have here now is basically this:

```
print +(map ...) . "123";
```

Because of the concatenation, `map` is being called in scalar context. And in scalar context, `map` no longer returns a list of values, but the size of that list (an integer - 3 in this case).

The fix for that is to replace the `.` with a comma, so `map` is called in list context.

```
$ perl -Mwarnings -le 'print +(map { (q(a)..q(z))[rand(26)] } 1..3), "123"'
ntg123
```

So you were being burnt by a) the parentheses not doing what you wanted them to do and b) `map` being called in scalar context.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -le 'print join("",map { (q(a)..q(z))[rand(26)] } 1..3) . "123"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the whole line to be printed inside parenthesis and use a comma as separator:

```
perl -le 'print ( (map { (q(a)..q(z))[rand(26)] } 1..3) , "123")'
```

Comment: So, it's not a concatenation. It just uses comma for output.

Comment: @Kirby: Yes. You can't concatenate an array with a string, the array is evaluated in strig context, so it gives the length of the array.

Comment: got it. I didn't know the result of `map` is an array. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: The result of `map` is **not** an array. In list context, the return value from `map` is a list. In scalar context, it is the number of elements in that list. Lists are not arrays.